# Using python to insert a single escape character in front of specified character in a string

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a path string that I would like to use inside of a subprocess command. This path contains directories with a whitespace, so a string like "foo/foo bar/bar" would need to be converted to "foo/foo\ bar/bar" beforehand. I have tried

```
path = "foo/foo bar/bar"
path = path.replace(" ","\\ ")
```

which results in "foo/foo\\ bar/bar"

I have also tried

```
path = os.path.normpath(path)
```

which changes nothing and

```
path = repr(path.replace(" ","\\ "))
```

which returns "foo/foo\\\\ bar/bar"

Is there a good solution to this while still using subprocess or os.system to call the command?

Comment: What about:  path = "\"foo/foo bar/bar\""

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The question title states you want to replace a specific character and in the question body you demonstrate that you are able to do so, so it seems there is no problem at all.

Comment: @a_guest I adjusted the question, the backslashes were being escaped. I am unable to insert a singular backslash into the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be expecting to put the entire command in a string and letting a shell parse it. Call subprocess with a list of arguments to avoid any need for quoting:

```
path = "foo/foo bar/bar"
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l", path])
```